# Using java annotation to parse a String based on Indices

Tags: java, spring, annotations, annotation-processing

I am trying to parse a line based on location of characters into properties , something  like what an external library like beanIo does but without really using beanIo(http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#BuilderApiAndAnnotations)

I would like to use annotations and this is where I am struggling, I don't think I understand them enough.
My use case:

```
String stringToParse = "0_2_4_MYNAME_MYAGE_";
```

The object I am to build after parsing the above string should be something like :

```
Record record = new Record(stringToParse); // this should create a key value pairs
/*record = < 
     "Age":  Field{name:"Age",value:"MYAGE", at:13, length:5}
     "Name": Field{name:"Name",value:"MYNAME", at:6, length:6}
>
```

I want to achieve this with annontation although I don't completely understand how they are read or should be read, this is what I have right now:

My Field Annontation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface  Field {
    public String name();
    public int at();
    public int length();
    public String value() default "[unassigned]"; //  should be determined using the other values, not passed-in
}
```

My Record annontation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Record {
  //Not sure what should goes here. Maybe: public HashMap<String, Field> record
}
```

This is how I use it in a class

```
@Record
public class PersonInfoLine {
   @Field(at = 5, length = 6)
   private String name;

   @Field(at = 13, length = 5)
   private String age;
}
```

Again when I instantiate PersonInfoLine  with a string I would like to get the "name" and "age", something like:

```
String stringToParse = "0_2_4_MYNAME_MYAGE_";

PersonInfoLine personInfoLine = new PersonInfoLine(stringToParse);
String name = personInfoLine.record.get("name").value; //MYNAME
String age = personInfoLine.record.get("age").value; //MYAGE
```

Don't really understand custom-annotations usage much so not even sure the above is how I should go about this..

Comment: You are actually looking for a java annotation processor tutorial aka APT, the processor you need to build isnt hard, so first manually write the code that you expect to be generated then following any APT tutorial to write a processor to generate the code instead.

Comment: thanks, would look into it

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design for what you're attempting to do.  If you're going to compile such things into the code, you'd be better off creating a utility to parse these values directly.  You can nothing by using annotations in this context.  Something like this is much simpler to read, understand, and maintain:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println(resolveValue("0_2_4_MYNAME_MYAGE_", 6, 6, "MUD"));
    System.out.println(resolveValue("", 6, 6, "MUD"));
    System.out.println(resolveValue("0_2_4_MYNAME_MYAGE_", 13, 5, "DIRT"));
    System.out.println(resolveValue("0_2_4_MYNAME_", 13, 5, "DIRT"));
}

private static String resolveValue(String data, int start, int length, String defaultValue) {
    try {
        return data.substring(start, start + length);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I want to go with annotation ,as I think it easier to save configuration in the annotation itself, as for my real scenarios I have a bunch of files who have different line types that  I have to parse, it would be easier for me to save the config in annotations rather then a separate config file,

Also i would prefer @Field(at=2, length=6) rather then calling a constructor or function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing , please feel free to comment on possible improvement:

I chucked the record class and only have 'Field' annotation, I renamed it to 'LineField' to get around the conflict with native 'Field' class

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface  LineField {
    public int at();
    public int length();
}
```

Called a utility function from my consumer-class to make a map of fieldName-fieldValue

```
public class Person {
    private static Field[] fields = BatchDetail2.class.getDeclaredFields();

    @LineField(at = 0, length = 8, literal = "6")
    private String name;

    @LineField(at = 12, length = 2)
    private String age;

    private  HashMap<String, String> fieldNameValueMap;


    public BatchDetail2(String personLine){ //personLine = "SAMUEL__234_31";
        fieldNameValueMap = LineProcessorUtil.getFieldValueMap(fields, personLine);
        name = fieldNameValueMap.get("recordTypeCode"); //SAMUEL__
        age = fieldNameValueMap.get("dfiAccountNumber"); //31

    }

}
```

My utiltyClass:

```
public class LineProcessorUtil {

    public static String getFieldValue(LineField field, String rawString){
        int startIndex = field.at();
        int endIndex = startIndex + field.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(rawString);
        return sb.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, String> getFieldValueMap(Field[] fields, String rawString){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        for(Field field:fields){
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(LineField.class)){
                String fieldName = field.getName();
                LineField lineField = field.getAnnotation(LineField.class);
                String fieldValue = getFieldValue(lineField, rawString);
                map.put(fieldName, fieldValue);

            }
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: You ended up by doing it in reflection.